# Creating different types of users in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to create an API to register, login and other things. two types of users
A teacher and a student , I'm using MongoDb and defining the schema.

```
   const UserSchema = new Schema({
   studentInfo : {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    birthday: Date,
    state: String,
    zip_code: String,
    address: String,
    phone_number: String,
     },
   teacherInfo : {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    birthday: Date,
    state: String,
    zip_code: String,
    address: String,
    phone_number: String,
    course: {
        title: String,
        price: Number,
        description: String
        }
    },
    role: String  
   });
```

is this a good approach? or there is a better way? 
I added the `role` field to perform route guarding on the front end.
I'm using `Nodejs` and `Express`.

any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of embedding both student and teacher object in the same document and you can simply get data with single query. Although you don't need to separately embed the common fields in object like name, email, password, phone_number etc. teacherInfo would be like this

```
teacherInfo : {
    course: {
        title: String,
        price: Number,
        description: String
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different schemas for student and teacher (as they are unique and you might need them independent sometimes), and make User as the base model.

```
  var User= new Schema({
       name: String,
       email: String,
       password:String,
       birthday: Date,
       state: String, 
       zip_code: String,
       address: String, 
       phone_number: String, 
       _teacher:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Teacher'},
       _student: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Student'}
 });
```

If _teacher has a value then the user can be considered as a teacher. 
If _student has a value then the user can be considered as a student.

```
      //Teacher Model
       var Teacher = new Schema({
       course: {
               title: String,
               price: Number,
               description: String
              },
        //other teacher's fields
       })


     //Student Schema
     var Student= new Schema({
          //student's fields if you need in future
       })
```

Comment: I don't really understand this approach. Can you please direct me to a documentation or an article explaining this approach in detail? thank you.

Comment: you can look at this link: https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/mongoose-referencing-schema-in-properties-and-arrays